# What does 'colt' stand for in this text?

Tags: meaning, synonyms, sentence-meaning

> The small locomotive engine, Number 4, came clanking, stumbling down from Selston — with seven full waggons. It appeared round the corner with loud threats of speed, but the **colt** that it startled from among the gorse, which still flickered indistinctly in the raw afternoon, outdistanced it at a canter.

(The Odour of Chrysanthemums by D. H. Lawrence)

Comment: When you looked up "colt" in the dictionary, what did you find?

Comment: When you look up "colt, meaning" on Google you get "a young male horse that is usually not castrated and has not attained an arbitrarily designated age (as four years" from [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/colt).  When you look up just "colt" the first entries are about Colt Manufacturing, i.e., guns.  Possibly this confused you.

Answer (score 1):

There is a train, the Number 4 train, coming in from Selston, pulling seven wagons.

It turns a corner, and scares a young horse - the colt - which was in the gorse around the track.

The horse ran faster than the train was moving.

Answer (score 0):

Colt does not stand for anything. Did you look the word up? A colt is a young male horse.

Comment: I just couldn't catch the meaning of the sentence. Does it mean then, that the locomotive made a horse run? (It's not my mothertounge, you know..)

Comment: @CorvusAlba, I encourage you to check out our sister site, [ell.se]; it is more geared towards people for whom English is a second language and who are still learning things that the [elu.se] site considers "basic".

Comment: @CorvusAlba, you asked what the word "colt" stood for, not for the meaning of the sentence. Yes, the colt (young male horse) was startled (spooked, alarmed) by the train, and then ran.

Comment: Of course I looked up "colt" in the dictionary first. Now I see that the word order was not clear for me - I thought that the colt startled the engine and that the colt was some part of the mine machinery... Anyway, it is all clear now and I appreciate all your help and comments.